# sublis not substituting symbols when called from another package

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

In my function I am reading input from the user which is expected to be a lisp form given as a string e.g.:

```
(sym1 sym2 (sym3 sym4))
```

My goal is to substitute some of the symbols with other symbols e.g.:

```
(sublis '((sym1 . sym1%)
          (sym2 . sym2%))
        str)
```

Because I am getting the input as a string, I am first converting it to a lisp form. Here is how the final function looks like:

```
(defun sublis-when-string (str)
  (sublis '((sym1 . sym1%)
            (sym2 . sym2%))
          (read-from-string str)))
```

When I compile the function and run it in the REPL with `(sublis-when-string "(sym1 sym3 (sym2 sym4))")` I correctly get:

```
(SYM1% SYM3 (SYM2% SYM4))
```

However when I run the whole program the substitutions do not work:

```
(SYM1 SYM3 (SYM2 SYM4))
```

This lead me to believe that the problems is with the package. When I changed the package in the REPL the substitutions were still not working.

My question is: **How should I change my function so it works when called from other packages?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use your function independently from the package in which the symbols are read, you can change your definition by adding an explicit test: when the values to be checked are symbols, the `string=` operator is used instead of default `eql`. For instance:

```
(defun sublis-when-string (str)
  (sublis '((sym1 . sym1%)
            (sym2 . sym2%))
          (read-from-string str)
          :test (lambda (x y)
                  (if (and (symbolp x) (symbolp y))
                     (string= x y)
                     (eql x y)))))
```

See the definition of [`sublis`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_sublis.htm#sublis).

Comment: On SBCL when I run the function with `"(sym1 sym2 sym3)"` I get `The value
  (SYM1 SYM2 SYM3)
is not of type
  (OR (VECTOR CHARACTER) (VECTOR NIL) BASE-STRING SYMBOL
      CHARACTER)` with the last line of the backtrace being: `(STRING= (SYM1 SYM2 SYM3) SYM1)`

Comment: @tsikov, sorry I didn't checked the function. `Sublis` performs a “recursive” check, by checking all the subtrees encountered, so I changed the definition to use `string=` only when two symbols are compared.

Answer (score 4):

You can define a package for your user:

```
(defpackage :my-user (:use) (:export #:sym1 #:sym2))
```

Of course, the exported symbols are the one you need to add in your substitution list. And then, you bind the `*package*` variable before reading:

```
(let ((*package* (find-package :my-user)))
  (read-from-string string))
```

Notice that all the symbols will be read from the `:my-user` package.
Depending on how much you trust the source of your strings, you can also set [`*read-eval*`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_rd_eva.htm) to nil and define a minimalistic readtable too:

- disable array notation that allocate very large arrays like `#n()` (bad user exhausting memory on purpose)
- make `:` a terminating character to make qualified symbols throw an error (bad user interning symbols in other packages)

Comment: Beautiful! However Renzo's solution also works and he was first, so I accepted his answer. Also I have to sync two lists of symbols - one for the exporting and the other - for the substitution. BTW you made an excellent point - where can I read more about safeguards to sanitise input from users?

Comment: @tsikov No problem about accepting Renzo's fine answer. I don't have a resource about best practices for sanitizing user input; it might depend on many different criteria and if you want to be truly paranoid it can go very far (add a timeout, limit memory, etc). For the array notation, I think I remember it was a potential problem in Clojure that was fixed. Just like testing, I generally try to think about "what if" situations. Can't really say more, I'd love to have a guide too